# Are these white bits mold?

Tags: health, beans

I bought some coffee beans today. When I poured them into a jar, I found some white bits. Are they mold? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell, especially as the photo is rather blurry. (Any chance you can get a better one? ) Off the cuff, I’d check for what could be webbing from pantry moths. But I can’t see it well enough for an answer. Do you still have the packaging and could check that too?

Comment: Dear @Stephie. Thanks for your reply. They are dissolvable in water, it seems to me they are coffeemate powder since there were some in the next box in the shop, however, I was not sure about it.

Comment: good to hear - feel free to self-answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the picture I believe that these white spots are something form when he beans have been harvested or they have been sugar and sprinkled when the manufacture was selling this product.

Comment: "something form when he beans have been harvested", Impossible, these white dots looks easily removable, which means during the process of shipping, roasting, and packing, it definitely would have fallen off.